# Build promotion using jenkinsfile upon approval

Tags: .net, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to promote my build to production using jenkins file only if it is approved by change management using servicenow change ticket ticket or by manual approval.

I want something like:
- Prod build can only be triggered manually if it is approved by manager(he/she should receive the approval mail with the link to approve/reject)
         or
- if the ServiceNow change ticket associated with the change is approved by all the approvers, if (changeticket== "APPROVED") then you can trigger the build deployment in production.

My jenkinsfile would look something like this(this is a sample code)

```
  pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
  dotnet = 'path\to\dotnet.exe'
              }

  stages {
  stage('Checkout') {
  steps {
  git credentialsId: 'userId', url: 
  'https://github.com/NeelBhatt/SampleCliApp', branch: 'master'
     }
         }
   stage('Restore PACKAGES') {
   steps {
    bat "dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.Config"
         }
                              }
   stage('Clean') {
   steps {
   bat 'dotnet clean'
         }
                  }
   stage('Build') {
   steps {
   bat 'dotnet build --configuration Release'
         }
                 }
   stage('Pack') {
   steps {
   bat 'dotnet pack --no-build --output nupkgs'
         }
                 }
   stage('Publish') {
   steps {
   bat "dotnet nuget push **\\nupkgs\\*.nupkg -k yourApiKey -s            
   http://myserver/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-internal-stable/com/sample"
         }
                    }
      }
      }
```

Thanks in advance!
Piyush

Answer (score 6):

You need to add an INPUT step in our Pipeline to ask for user input and take action on the result.  In your case, you can add an email step to send an email link to this Pipeline that will ask for an approval.  And the Deployment step will take action after the Input step has been approved.

```
stage("Stage with input") {
    steps {
      def userInput = false
        script {
            def userInput = input(id: 'Proceed1', message: 'Promote build?', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'Please confirm you agree with this']])
            echo 'userInput: ' + userInput

            if(userInput == true) {
                // do action
            } else {
                // not do action
                echo "Action was aborted."
            }

        }    
    }  
}
```

Optionally: You can surround this with a timeout so it won't wait forever.

There are a few different ways to send an email, but this is one of them:

```
// send to email
emailext (
  subject: "Waiting for your Approval! Job: '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
  body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
              <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
  recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

Please modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for providing your valuable inputs however, I am not a developer and my coding skills are not up to the mark, can you please also share the code for email when you have sometime. I really appreciate your efforts on this.

Cheers!

Comment: I modified my post with an email example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your efforts.