# Trigger email with Approve / Reject button from Jenkins pipelinejob

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I am new to Jenkins pipeline. I got a requirement to generate an email after sonarqube scan to decide whether to approve/reject build.

I have configured sonarqube in my jenkins pipeline script, post the sonarqube analysis if issues are encountered then I need to trigger a mail to an approver with accept/reject button in mail.
If approver click accept button then build should move to next stage and deploy in production environment and if reject button is clicked then build should fail.

I see a "Promote Build" plugin , but it seems to be applicable only for freestyle job.If promote build works for pipeline script please help me with sample script.

Can someone help me with pipeline script for my requirement.

Thanks,
Karthik P.

Comment: You can have look on this post. This answer contains almost like your retirement  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634943/8053714

Comment: Do we have any other way other than input, similar to "promote" option where approver will be redirected to a page with approve or reject button. I am working something like an email should trigger which has approve and reject button(if possible else a link in mail which will take to a page which has approve and reject button) and click on approve or reject, in jenkins we should capture the user details who approved/rejected. Apologizes for such a ling requirement, I am new bee to devops so not sure about possibility, your help is highly helpful for me.  Thanks in advance.